# Alternative to "ArrayFormula" in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to create a production scheduler in google sheets.
Each tab is for a different department to fill out.
Ideally, one person enters the Order summary in the first tab. The next tab gets updated and someone else fills in the relevant details and it goes to the final tab.
Is there a way to automatically add rows to other tabs while having the ability to sort?

I have been using =arrayformula() initially but I realise the if I try sorting in other tabs, it messes up that sheet. I also tried =sheet1!A1, but I want to restrict as much input by other members.

Comment: `QUERY()` function has capability to sort data itself. Also `SORT()` may come into picture.

Comment: Have in mind that if you add additional columns in Sheet2 next to the data from Sheet1, when you sort Sheet1 it won't automatically sort the additonal columns from Sheet2. If that is your intention, you should all work in different columns in a general MasterSheet, or work in different sheets without sorting; and then summarize and sort in a new tab that grabs data from your different sheets

Answer (score 0):

sort it by formula. example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(A2:C; 2; (D1="asc")*1))
```

where D1 is a dropdown with `asc,desc` and we sort the whole array via B (2nd) column